# c++ error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘distances’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting an error on the first line of the below code. The error is

```
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘distances’
```

and I don't get what is actually wrong with it. I am using ideone, if that helps, but I don't think that is causing the problem.

```
vector<string> Most(bitset<4> treasure, int distance, string path, int p, int[] distances, string[] paths){
    for(int i = 1; i<4; i++){
        if(100>=distances[p*4+1+i]+distances[i*5+1]){
            Most(treasure, distance+distances[p*4+1+i], path.append(paths[p*4+1+i]),i, distances, paths);
        }
   }
    vector<string> test;
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Try `int distances[]`

Comment: He'll also need to change string[] paths to string paths[]

Answer (score 1):

Change these parameter declarations

```
int[] distances, string[] paths
```

to

```
int distances[], string paths[]
```

The syntax you use is valid in C# not in C++.

Are you sure that the function is valid? It is always returns an empty vector. And take into account that original object used as argument path will not be changed because it is passed by value to the function

Answer (score 0):

This compiles.. although I am not sure what it should do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

// I modified the function signature from "string[] paths" to "string* paths",
// the same for `int[] distances`
vector<string> Most(bitset<4> treasure, int distance, string path, int p, int* distances, string* paths)
{
    for(int i = 1; i<4; i++){
        if(100>=distances[p*4+1+i]+distances[i*5+1]){
            Most(treasure, distance+distances[p*4+1+i], path.append(paths[p*4+1+i]),i, distances, paths);
        }
    }
    vector<string> test;
    return test;
}

// it is better if you post runnable code
int main() {

}
```

If you still have troubles, try to modify your code to be minimal, but runnable. ;)